# Move <a> tag to new line if it's content flows out of the first line?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following, move  tag to a new line if its content flow from one line to another, so you can see what I mean here http://jsfiddle.net/sNyzX/ Firs example (red) shows situation I have now and second example (orange) shows desired effect, however without that `<br>` tag. Can this be achieved with plain html and css, if not jQuery solution will do as well.

```
<div id="example1">
    Hi there This is some text and <a href="#"> this is the link! </a>
</div>

<div id="example2">
    Hi there This is some text and <br> <a href="#"> this is the link! </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#example1 {
    background: red;
    width: 145px;
}

#example2 {
    background: orange;
    width: 145px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: jsFiddle is down for me. You're going to have to post the code from the fiddle here.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry for that, didn't think it would be of any significant use for folks here, as it is mainly demonstration that shows what I meant. Thank you for adding the code it by the way ;)

Comment: @Ilya: If it isn't useful for folks here, your question stands at risk of being closed as too localized. I wasn't the one who added the code by the way - I can't even load jsFiddle right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
a {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: With this solution the `<a>` link will overflow the content div making a weird look. http://jsfiddle.net/sNyzX/3/

Comment: @Christian I see, however this issue did not appear on my website, works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can!

Just put

```
#example1 a {
    display: block   
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sNyzX/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
 word-break:break-word;
```

for long word to break into lines.

```
#example1 {
    background: red;
    width: 145px;
    word-break:break-word;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sNyzX/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your style-sheet

```
#example1 a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set display property of link to block, it will always move the link to a new line.

```
#example1 a {
    display: block;
}
```

You can check out this page to know how display property work:
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-display.php